# Working around InvokeRequired in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-services, invoke

I'm trying to make a simple windows service.

All this service does is change the volume for one device when another device's volume is altered. It currently works as an application, and is only two Subs and a dll to function.

Basically an event handler is created on the Form Load:

```
AddHandler device.AudioEndpointVolume.OnVolumeNotification, AddressOf volume
```

Which calls the sub:

```
Private Sub volume(data As CoreAudioApi.AudioVolumeNotificationData)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New AudioEndpointVolumeNotificationDelegate(AddressOf volume), data)
    Else
        loopback.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar = data.MasterVolume
        loopback.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = data.Muted
    End If

End Sub
```

Now in a windows service I can't use invoke, and when I remove it the error `The function evaluation requires all threads to run` is thrown.

What I believe is happening is that the control data and loopback (which are the controls of the audio Device accessed via the CoreAudioApi.dll) is not resolving without the invoke, but I don't know how to make them resolve properly.

Comment: Have you tried without the "If Me.InvokeRequired...", just leaving the Else part?. Windows Services are disallowed from interacting with the Desktop, and a windows form cannot be showed from Service, probably the invoke is not be required.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Determine changes of master audio volume using NAudio.dll from: https://github.com/SjB/NAudio

```
Imports NAudio.CoreAudioApi

Public Class Form1
Private enumer As MMDeviceEnumerator = New MMDeviceEnumerator()
Private dev As MMDevice = enumer.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia)
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    AddHandler dev.AudioEndpointVolume.OnVolumeNotification, AddressOf AudioEndpointVolume_OnVolumeNotification
End Sub

Private Sub AudioEndpointVolume_OnVolumeNotification(ByVal data As AudioVolumeNotificationData)
    ' This shows data.MasterVolume, you can do whatever you want here
    Me.Text = CInt(data.MasterVolume.ToString() * 100) & " Mute=" & data.Muted
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

If I remove the if around the invoke statement so it just has the line:

```
Me.Invoke(New AudioEndpointVolumeNotificationDelegate(AddressOf volume), data)
```

followed by the other two lines it throws the error:

"'Invoke' is not a member of 'VolumeSet.VolumeSet'"

So I don't think invoke can be used inside a windows service at all.

But thanks for the idea!

Comment: This is NOT an answer!